# Domain Driven Design Entity Advice for a Novice

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to learn Domain Driven Design. At the moment I'm putting together a context map for a dummy personal project designed to store information about clients and leads (there's also an email template engine and some other bits).

I've stumbled on a small hurdle; the problem I have is that I've created a bounded context for storing information about clients and companies. There are two types of client, Proxy clients who sub-contract and end clients.

I'm not sure if I should just be modelling this as client with a client type value type or as separate domain entities for clients and proxy clients? Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: domain]

---

**Please Note**

The diagram above isn't complete so there are some links missing. If I'm doing something obviously wrong here please don't hesitate to let me know.

I'm also using arrow heads instead of upstream / downstream as I think they're a little better visually.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to model this will depend on the requirements for your application and the business domain.

There is something that seems to me is missing for `ProxyClients`. If they sub-contract, they should be involved in some kind of `Project` for an `EndClient` maybe?

I'll just assume that this is the case and add `Project` to the model.

Now, can a client be one time an `EndClient` for one `Project` and another time a `SubClient` for another?

If the answer is yes then you will need a separate `ClientEntity` that can have a `ClientType` or `Role` assigned to it for a `Project`. The `Role` doesn't make sense on it's own, it exists only for a `Project`.

An advantage of using `ClientType` or `ClientRole` as a separate concept in your model is that it's dynamic and you can change the type of a `Client` or assign multiple types/roles.

Using different entities will prevent you from doing this. If later in the life-cycle of your application the requirements change you will have to refactor to the other design. Leaving the old design and converting a `SubClient` to `EndClient` probably won't be possible or you will need to store all the information for all projects done by this `EndClient`. Another way to deal with this is to have one client have copies in both `ProxyClients` and `EndClients`

On the other hand if you don't need the flexibility of the design with separate `Type/Role` you will be better of with different entities. This has the advantage of having a clean separation of what type of a client you are dealing with and will make the system simpler.

For more information on this topic check [this article](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf)

Now onto the model and the design.

When someone answers your question there are two thing that a person can do. One is to answer the direct question that you are asking.

Another is to notice problems with you design, model etc. and give you feedback for it.

You said that somethings are missing, but they are important. I did answer your concrete question, but the small amount of information prevents me from giving you more feedback on your design and give you some pointers on where you mistakes may be.

One of the things I don't uderstand is `ProxyClient`. Does a `Company` `SubContract` for a `Client` and that's why this client is a `ProxyClient` for this `Company` or is the `Company` hired to do a `Project` for an `EndClient` and it hires a `SubContractor` that you call a `ProxyClient`.

This point is important for your design yet it's not clear. Because if you are in the second case then I would say that your concepts may need to change. For example you have a `SubContractor` doing the work and won't call it a `ProxyClient` as it doens't make sense. This will change the whole model with new concepts.

Next time try to give more information or try to derive a simpler and more clearer case. Sometimes the original case is complex, so you may need to present a similar yet simpler case that faces the same problem so that people don't get confused. Also give more information on your application and your domain. How things should work and what are the relationships between them.

Comment: hi @expandable. Thanks for looking at my question. I thought the whole domain might be a little complex so I tried to give a sort of parallel problem. So the actual problem is that I am the sub contractor sometimes but not always. Company isn't my company it's the customer/client companies. So the problem is that sometimes I might be working with a recruiter. Sometimes the recruiter might have a client who wants to sub contract me.

Comment: Given your comments I think the client type might be the better option. Then I can have more flexibility to handle different situations. I think this would make "client type" a value and client an entity.

Comment: I did notice that the problem has complex relationships. I just wanted to point that it can be confusing to developers who have experience in DDD as they can see that there is more yet cannot make sense of it without having more information. Explanations of complex models or simplifying them is hard :) In such a complex model using a value object `ClientType` is the best way to go.

Comment: That's what I'd sort of done in the image above but I spent ages thinking about whether or not it's the right thing to do. Thank you for your really thorough explanation. That's exactly what I needed. I've just got so many unknown unknowns at the moment.